# Change '-1' answer,when indexof not found any matches

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my original code.If indexof function not find any result,print out -1.I would like to change it.

```
function searchForString() {
  var str = document.getElementById("string").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = str;
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  var button = document.getElementById("search");
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.textContent = "Index of string \"" + input.value + "\": " + str.indexOf(input.value);
}
```

I tried to create a new variable like this,and tried to create an if function but its not working.

```
var hiba = "hiba";
if (output == -1) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = hiba;
} else {
  output.textContent = "Index of string \"" + input.value + "\": " + str.indexOf(input.value);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you getting your vars mixed up, on the one hand you have `output == -1`, and on the other hand your using the `output` to be an element with id `output`,..  Maybe introduce another var, maybe called idx..

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if `output` is equal to `-1` when you want to check if the index returned by `indexOf` is `-1`. Something like this should work.

```
function searchForString() {
    var str = document.getElementById("string").value;
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.innerHTML = str;
    var index = str.indexOf(input);
    if (index === -1) {
        output.textContent = "hiba";
    }
    else {
        output.textContent = "Index of string \"" + input + "\": " + index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ternary operator (`?`) to change the value of it depending on whether it's `-1` or not. (Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```js
var str = document.getElementById("string").innerHTML;
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var button = document.getElementById("search");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
function searchForString() {
  output.textContent = str.indexOf(input.value) == -1 ? "String \"" + input.value + "\" not found" : "Index of string \"" + input.value + "\": " + str.indexOf(input.value); // if string == -1, say "String not found", otherwise say index of string
}
```

```html
String: <span id="string">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span><br />
<label for="input">Find this character: </label><input id="input" type="text"><br />
<button id="search" onclick="searchForString()">Search</button><br />
<div id="output"></div>
```